# wp_add_inline_style() not working?

Tags: themes

I'm working on my portfolio and I need to set a custom background color and image for each post in my 'Portfolio' category. I used custom data to store the color and the image url, and i'm trying to print the new css on my page.

I can't use true inline css (like style="") because of a JS script I made which uses it already and makes conflict.

So I tried use wp_add_inline_style :

```
<?php // File "content-thumbnail.php" used for each post. So, we're in the Loop here. ?>

<div class="post-circle">
    <?php lethal_post_circle_background(get_the_ID()); ?>
    <div class="post-circle-summary">
        <p class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <p class="post-categories"><?php lethal_post_categories_portfolio(); ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="post-circle-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

And then the script to add the style :

```
<?php
function lethal_post_circle_background($id){
    $custombgcolor = get_post_meta( $id, 'bgcolor', true );
    $custombgimage = get_post_meta( $id, 'bgimage', true );
    if($custombgcolor | $custombgimage){
        $css = '.post-'.$id.' .post-circle{
        background:';
        if($custombgcolor) $css .= $custombgcolor . ' ';
        if($custombgimage) $css .= 'url("' . $custombgimage . '")';
        $css.= ';}';

        wp_add_inline_style('lethal-style', $css);
    }

}
```

The problem is that the genereted style isn't in the generated html file, but the wp_add_inline_style() function returned true (so I think everything is ok).
I don't have any error or Notice messages.

Do you know what is the problem ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook `wp_add_inline_style` to `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Check the [codex example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style). Something like (not tested):

```
function lethal_post_circle_background(){
    global $post;
    $id = $post->ID;
    $custombgcolor = get_post_meta( $id, 'bgcolor', true );
    $custombgimage = get_post_meta( $id, 'bgimage', true );
    if($custombgcolor | $custombgimage){
        $css = '.post-'.$id.' .post-circle{
        background:';
        if($custombgcolor) $css .= $custombgcolor . ' ';
        if($custombgimage) $css .= 'url("' . $custombgimage . '")';
        $css.= ';}';

        wp_add_inline_style('lethal-style', $css);
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lethal_post_circle_background' );
```

Comment: But if I've 5 posts on my page, I need to call this function 5 times, with another ID each time, right ?
Can I hook this function once per post ?